# How to deploy C# Sql project on clients/target machine?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have developed an inventory system in C# ,database used is SQL server .Now my problem is how to deploy my project with database and run it on client's machine i have 1 more week remaining in delivering this project .I tried many blogs and sites but all in vain and i did not get any good resource which clearify me all this scenerio.The current publishing process does not have a database file and showing me an error :

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections
```

Please any suggestions would be highly appreciable?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server 2012!

Comment: Did you install Sql Server on the target machine (or in a machine reachable by your application) ?

Comment: Have you tried reading the error message and trying to look for reasons? That message is very explicit about what the error can be, you know. It even has instructions.

Comment: @Steve..Yes Sql Server is installed on target machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, SQL Server have network access disabled after a fresh install. You need to use the  SQL Configuration Manager to allow remote connections to the instance.

See this post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

http://www.romankagan.com/?p=118

If after this you still can't connect, verify that SQL Server ports are not been blocked by the machine firewall.